# panel setBackground is messing up colors of JLabels within

Tags: java, panel, jlabel

Here's my code in problem. 
The problem is that if I use "white" to set the Background of panel, the colors of icon in the "pic" JLabel become very light.
If I use "black" instead, the colors of pic JLabel are visible.
It doesn't matter what colors I use in the pic JLabel. They all get lightened as soon as the panel is set to white.

Is there any other way I can set background color of the panel without affecting the colors of the JLabel within?

```
Color black = new Color( 20, 20, 20, 255 );
Color white = new Color( 255, 255, 255, 255 );

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize( 1200, 500 );
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
frame.setResizable( false );

JPanel panel= new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add( panel );
panel.setLayout( null );
panel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("panel");
panel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(" ");

// this is the line that causes problem
panel.setBackground( black );


JLabel pic = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( showBaseImage() ) );
panel.add( pic );
pic.setSize( 1200, 500 );
pic.setLocation( 1, 1);
pic.setBackground( black );


public BufferedImage showBaseImage(){
BufferedImage c = new BufferedImage( 1200, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
Graphics2D gg= c.createGraphics();
gg.setPaint( new Color( 125, 0, 125, 255  ));
gg.fillRect( 0,0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight() );

gg.setPaint( new Color( 255, 255, 225, 255  ));
imgFont = new Font( "Arial", Font.BOLD, 45 );
gg.setFont( imgFont );

gg.drawString( "Write something", 20, 20 );
gg.dispose();
return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use label.setOpaque(true) to allow your label to be opaque.
Its implementation comes from JComponent which is false by default.

> Note that labels are not opaque by default. If you need to paint the label's background, it is recommended that you turn its opacity property to "true". The following code snippet shows how to do this.

```
label.setOpaque(true);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks so much

Comment: It's too much :)  It's a common trick with Swing.
If the response addresses your problem, think of accepting it :)